# Dynamic Generated Script Should Appear on all pages in DNN

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke-module

My Client need a DNN module in which the dynamic generated Javascript should appear in the footer of the whole web portal. I have generated the code but it only appears on one page of the portal as soon as the page closes the script gone. as this script generated from a Module and that module is in only one page. so donno what to do with this situation, any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As you said you need to keep the dynamically generated script in `Footer` control also.

For that, Can you keep the `Literal control` in the `Footer section`. Now, whenever the `JavaScript` is generated dynamically, you have to keep the information in `Session` variable.

Like this...

```
public class SessionCollection
{
  public static String DynamicJavaScript
  {
    get
    {
       return Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["DynamicJavaScript"]);
    }
    set
    {
       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["DynamicJavaScript"] = value;
    }
  }
}
```

As you know the Flow of the Control goes like below.

> 1. First Web Page will be executed.
> 2. Next Master Page will be executed.
> 3. Finally User Control will be executed.

Now, once the Master page will execute, the `Session` value can be accessed in the `Footer` Part. I am assuming that the Footer Contents are directly been used in `Master Page` or another `User Control` is prepared and used in the `Master` Page.

Hope this will be useful...